# Swift how to avoid override init?(coder) in subclass

Tags: ios, swift

A common annoyance with using Swift is that subclasses must implement init?(coder) even if you don't use Storyboard.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

It's not elegant. How can I avoid overwriting it in a subclass?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a base class, override it in the base class and add the `@available(*, unavailable)` flag so that its subclasses can avoid overriding the method, and this method also removed from code completion.

```
@available(*, unavailable)
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```